# Dropzone.js how to add hidden input with value to uploaded image

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am having problems with adding hidden input field to uploaded images using dropzone.js.

What i am trying to do is to use dropzonejs to upload images to the website and then having possibility with jquery sortable to drag and change order of the images.

I've managed to make it working everything so far except when i use separated input array the order of the images is not changed on drag and drop.

For this to work i need to find a way to add hidden input to the image template when image is uploaded.

Here is the code i use in .php file

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div id="media-uploader" class="dropzone"></div>
    <div id="uploaded-media" class="hidden">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Right now when image is uploaded a hidden input field is added to #uploaded-media but i need to change that and add hidden input in uploaded image template holder.

Here is what it looks like now when image is uploaded

```
<div id="media-uploader" class="dropzone dz-clickable ui-sortable dz-started">
  <div class="dz-default dz-message">
    <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
  </div>
  <div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-image-preview dz-success dz-complete">  
    <div class="dz-image"><img data-dz-thumbnail="" alt="DSC_3771-Edit.jpg" src=""></div>  
    <div class="dz-details">    
      <div class="dz-size"><span data-dz-size=""><strong>0.9</strong> MB</span></div>    
      <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name="">DSC_3771-Edit.jpg</span></div>  
    </div>  
    <div class="dz-progress">
      <span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress="" style="width: 100%;"></span>
    </div>  
    <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage=""></span></div>  
    <div class="dz-success-mark">      </div>  
    <div class="dz-error-mark">      </div>
    <a class="dz-remove" href="javascript:undefined;" data-dz-remove="">Remove file</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only small change i need is it to look like this

```
<div id="media-uploader" class="dropzone dz-clickable ui-sortable dz-started">
  <div class="dz-default dz-message">
    <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
  </div>
  <div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-image-preview dz-success dz-complete">  
    <div class="dz-image"><img data-dz-thumbnail="" alt="DSC_3771-Edit.jpg" src=""></div>  
    <div class="dz-details">    
      <div class="dz-size"><span data-dz-size=""><strong>0.9</strong> MB</span></div>    
      <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name="">DSC_3771-Edit.jpg</span></div>  
    </div>  
    <div class="dz-progress">
      <span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress="" style="width: 100%;"></span>
    </div>  
    <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage=""></span></div>  
    <div class="dz-success-mark">      </div>  
    <div class="dz-error-mark">      </div>
    <a class="dz-remove" href="javascript:undefined;" data-dz-remove="">Remove file</a>
    **<input type="hidden" name="media-ids[]" id="media-ids[]" class="media-ids" value="812">**
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the dropzone configuration

```
    // Dropzone file uploader
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone ("#media-uploader", {
    url: dropParam.upload,
    autoProcessQueue: true,
    parallelUploads: 1,
    uploadMultiple: false,
    maxFilesize: 3,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    maxFiles: 10,
    success: function (file, response) {
        file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
        file['attachment_id'] = response; // push the id for future reference
        $('#uploaded-media').append( $('<input type="hidden" name="media-ids[]" id="media-ids[]" class="media-ids" value="' + response +'">') );

    },
    error: function (file, response) {
        file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
    },
    // update the following section is for removing image from library
    removedfile: function(file) {
        var attachment_id = file.attachment_id;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: dropParam.delete,
            data: {
                media_id : attachment_id
            }
        });
        $('input.media-ids[type=hidden]').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == attachment_id) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
        var _ref;
        return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry, I don't get what you want. add style="display: none" to the tag?

Comment: I want hidden input field with image id added to each image element. Check the difference between uploaded image example previews. Second one have <input type="hidden" name="media-ids[]" id="media-ids[]" class="media-ids" value="812"> as an example

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution, the code below will add an input field to each uploaded image upon successful upload

```
myDropzone.on("success", function(file, response) {
    $(file.previewElement).append( $('<input type="hidden" name="media-ids[]" id="media-ids[]" class="media-ids dz-media-id" value="' + response +'">') );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $("div#js-dropzone").dropzone({
    url: "/api/mmm/orders/fileupload",
    method: 'POST',
    maxFilesize: 5, // MB
    previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
    success: function (response) {
        $(response.previewElement).append('<input type="hidden" name="fileupload" value="' + JSON.parse(response.xhr.response).fileName + '" />');
    }
});
```

Comment: this is the right idea but "success" is not a valid configuration option.  You'd need to add an event listener inside "init"